# Bosonization of Fermionic theory with boundary

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, bosonization

Consider massless Thirring model

\begin{equation}
-\psi^\dagger_R(x)\partial_x\psi_R(x)+i\psi^\dagger_L(x)\partial_x\psi_L(x)+g\psi^\dagger_R(x)\psi_R(x)\psi^\dagger_L(x)\psi_L(x)
\end{equation}

Using the Bosonization dictionary, one can map this to a compactified free bosonic theory.

Now, say the Fermionic theory is defined on a line [-L,L] and following boundary conditions are imposed
\begin{equation}
\psi_R(-L)+e^{a}\psi_L(-L)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \psi_R(+L)+e^{-a}\psi_L(+L)=0
\end{equation}
which when $a=0$ is the the boundary condition where left mover reflects and becomes right mover at the edges and vice versa.

Now, the question is: Can this still be bosonized? If so, how does the boundary condition look like in the bosonic theory?